# Definite integral notation correct?

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm having trouble understanding some of the notation for definite integrals. Is this right?

$$ \int_1^2 (\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{4}{x^3}) \, dx$$

$$ \int_1^2 x^{-2} - 4x^{-3} \, dx$$

$$ = \int_1^2 x^{-2} \, dx- \int_1^2 4x^{-3} \, dx$$

$$  \left[ -x^{-1} \right ]_1^2 - \left[\frac{4x^{-2}}{-2} \right]_1^2$$

Is this notation right? Or should it be:

$$\left[ -x^{-1} -\frac{4x^{-2}}{-2} \right]_1^2 $$

Comment: It looks good either way. Note that $$[f(x)-g(x)]_a^b = (f(b)-g(b))-(f(a)-g(a)) = (f(b)-f(a)) - (g(b)-g(a)) = [f(x)]_a^b - [g(x)]_a^b$$

Comment: Second  line should be $=\int_1^2(x^{-2}-4x^{-3})\,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. Lord Shark is correct that the second line is better written

$$\int_1^2 \left(x^{-2} - 4x^{-3}\right) \, dx$$

since the length form $dx$ multiplies the entire function $x^{-2} - 4x^{-3}$ and not just the right term, but the potential for confusion in this case is nil.

Comment: What about my last 2 lines?

Comment: They're fine too.

Comment: Both are acceptable notation?

Comment: I don't know how many different ways I can say "yes it's fine" ;)